# template Matrix class with Static or dynamic size

Tags: c++11, matrix, template

I started implementing the folowing Matrix class in order to get a better understanding of templates classes in general. For now, it lacks a lot of features, it does very basic things:

- addition
- multiplication (only matrix X matrix multiplication is available here)
- transpose
- conversion to a string

Here are some points i think might be interesting

- The dimensions of the matrices can either be "static" or "dynamic". By static, i mean the number of rows / columns is not allowed to change even if the data is stored in an std::vector
- When adding two matrices together, the resulting matrix's dimension is static if at least one of the two operands is static.
- When multiplying two matrices together, the resulting matrix's dimension depends on the rows of the left hand side and the columns of the right hand side of the "*".
- The type of data contained in the returned matrix corresponds to the implicit cast of the types of the left and right sides of the expression. If the user decided to multiply a matrix of *Foos*, with a matrix of *Bars*, it's on him.
- The "changeSize" methode, when called on a static matrix will only throw if the requested change is different from the matrix size.
- I did not bother for now with the type of exception i used as this is more of an exercise than something that i will use in a real application.
- The reason i made it possible to instanciate Static or dynamic matrices is because i want it to be able to manage Vector X Matrix operations. As a vector is just a special case of matrices, i choose to made them into a single class. (in the style of Eigen, which my code is inspired from a used inteface point of view).

Is my use of the rvalues references and move semantics correct? (that is a notion i learned about last week, any advice can help)

What do you think could be improved about my code?

Is there any notion i should learn before continuing?

Were any design choices in terme of template parameters good or bad?

```
#ifndef UTILS_MATRIX_H_
#define UTILS_MATRIX_H_

#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace mat
{

  constexpr size_t DYNAMIC = static_cast<size_t>(-1); // [-] No matrix can be of this size... right?

  template<typename TYPE, size_t NBROWS, size_t NBCOLS>
  class Matrix
  {
    private:

      std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>> matrixData;             // [-] Contents of the Matrix as a 2D array
      static constexpr bool isRowStatic = NBROWS != DYNAMIC; // [-] Is the number of rows of this matrix editable at run time
      static constexpr bool isColStatic = NBCOLS != DYNAMIC; // [-] Is the number of columns of this matrix editable at run time

    public:

      /** @brief Default constructor
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      Matrix() :
          matrixData()
      {
        if ((NBROWS <= 0 and NBROWS != DYNAMIC) or (NBCOLS <= 0 and NBCOLS != DYNAMIC))
          throw std::runtime_error("The number of rows and columns of a static matrix must be positive integers");

        // In case of a dynamic shape, the matrix should not be instanciated
        if(isRowStatic and isColStatic)
          internalChangeSize(NBROWS, NBCOLS);
      }

      /** @brief Consutuctor for the static size matrix
       *  @param i_DefaultValue IN : Default value used to fill
       *         the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      Matrix(const TYPE &i_DefaultValue) :
          matrixData()
      {
        // error handling
        if (not isRowStatic or not isColStatic)
          throw std::runtime_error("The default value constructor can not be called on a Matrix with at least one dynamic component");

        if ((NBROWS <= 0 and NBROWS != DYNAMIC) or (NBCOLS <= 0 and NBCOLS != DYNAMIC))
          throw std::runtime_error("The number of rows and columns of a static matrix must be positive integers");

        internalChangeSize(NBROWS, NBCOLS, i_DefaultValue);
      }

      /** @brief Consutuctor for the dynamic size matrix without default value
       *
       *  @param i_Nbrows       IN : Number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param i_Nbcols       IN : Number of columns of the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      Matrix(const size_t i_Nbrows,
             const size_t i_Nbcols) :
          matrixData()
      {
        // error handling
        if (i_Nbrows <= 0 or i_Nbcols <= 0)
          throw std::runtime_error("The number or rows and columns has to be a positive integer");

        // If one dimension is static, ignore the related constructor parameters
        size_t NbRows = i_Nbrows;
        size_t NbCols = i_Nbcols;
        if(isRowStatic)
          NbRows = NBROWS;
        if(isColStatic)
          NbCols = NBCOLS;

        internalChangeSize(NbRows, NbCols, TYPE());
      }

      /** @brief Consutuctor for the dynamic size matrix with default value
       *
       *  @param i_Nbrows       IN : Number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param i_Nbcols       IN : Number of columns of the matrix
       *  @param i_DefaultValue IN : Default value used to fill the
       *                             matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      Matrix(const size_t i_Nbrows,
             const size_t i_Nbcols,
             const TYPE &i_DefaultValue) :
          matrixData()
      {
        // error handling
        if (i_Nbrows <= 0 or i_Nbcols <= 0)
          throw std::runtime_error("The number or rows and columns has to be a positive integer");

        // If one dimension is static, ignore the related constructor parameters
        size_t NbRows = i_Nbrows;
        size_t NbCols = i_Nbcols;
        if(isRowStatic)
          NbRows = NBROWS;
        if(isColStatic)
          NbCols = NBCOLS;

        internalChangeSize(NbRows, NbCols, i_DefaultValue);
      }

      /** @brief Copy constructor
       *
       *  @param i_otherMatrix IN : Matrix to be copied
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      Matrix(const Matrix<TYPE, NBROWS, NBCOLS>& i_otherMatrix):
          matrixData()
      {
        if(not i_otherMatrix.isEmpty())
          {
          changeSize(i_otherMatrix.getNbRows(), i_otherMatrix.getNbCols());
          matrixData = i_otherMatrix.matrixData;
          }
      }

      /** @brief Move constructor
       *
       *  @param i_otherMatrix IN : Matrix to be moved
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      Matrix(Matrix<TYPE, NBROWS, NBCOLS>&& i_otherMatrix):
          matrixData()
      {
        matrixData = std::move(i_otherMatrix.matrixData);
      }

      /** @brief getter for the matrix data vector
       *
       *  @return std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>>&.
       */
      const std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>>& getMatrixData() const
      {
        return matrixData;
      }

      /** @brief getter for the number or rows
       *
       *  @return size_t
       */
      size_t getNbRows() const
      {
        return matrixData.size();
      }

      /** @brief getter for the number or columns
        *
        *  @return size_t
        */
      size_t getNbCols() const
      {
        if(matrixData.size() > 0)
          return matrixData[0].size();
        else
          return 0;
      }

      /** @brief is the Matrix is empty
        *
        *  @return bool
        */
      bool isEmpty() const
      {
        return getNbRows() == 0 or getNbCols() == 0;
      }

      /** @brief function used to retrieve the shape of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbRows OUT : Number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbCols OUT : Number of columns of the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      std::pair<size_t, size_t> shape() const
      {
        return std::pair<size_t, size_t>(getNbRows(), getNbCols());
      }

      /** @brief function used to print the contents of the
       *         matrix formatted into a string
       *
       *  @return std::string
       */
      std::string toString(int i_Precision = 10) const
      {
        std::ostringstream SS;

        // if 0 lines representation is an empty bracket
        if(matrixData.size() == 0)
          SS << "| |" << std::endl;

        // This will align the floating point numbers
        SS << std::showpoint;
        SS << std::setprecision(i_Precision);
        for(auto& Row : matrixData)
        {
          SS << "|";
          for(auto& Value : Row)
          {
            SS << " " << Value << " ";
          }
          SS << "|" << std::endl;
        }
        return SS.str();
      }

      /** @brief function used to change the size of the matrix
       *         This method does not require a default value,
       *         hence it is default initialized
       *
       *  @param i_NbRows IN : New number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbCols IN : New number of columns of the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void changeSize(const size_t i_NbRows, const size_t i_NbCols)
      {
        // Error handling
        if (i_NbRows <= 0 or i_NbCols <= 0)
          throw std::runtime_error("The number or rows and columns has to be a positive integer");

        if (isRowStatic and NBROWS != i_NbRows)
          throw std::runtime_error("You cannot change the number of rows, the matrix row size is static.");

        if(isColStatic and NBCOLS != i_NbCols)
          throw std::runtime_error("You cannot change the number of columns, the matrix columns size is static.");

        internalChangeSize(i_NbRows, i_NbCols);
      }

      /** @brief function used to change the size of the matrix
       *         This method does not require a default value,
       *         hence it is default initialized
       *
       *  @param i_NewShape IN : New shape of the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void changeSize(const std::pair<size_t, size_t>& i_NewShape)
      {
        changeSize(i_NewShape.first, i_NewShape.second);
      }

      /** @brief function used to change the size of the matrix
       *         This method requires a default value for filling
       *         any new row / column.
       *
       *  @param i_NbRows     IN : New number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbCols     IN : New number of columns of the matrix
       *  @param DefaultValue IN : Default value used to fill the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void changeSize(const size_t i_NbRows, const size_t i_NbCols, const TYPE &DefaultValue)
      {
        // error handling
        if (i_NbRows <= 0 or i_NbCols <= 0)
          throw std::runtime_error("The number or rows and columns has to be a positive integer");

        if (isRowStatic and NBROWS != i_NbRows)
          throw std::runtime_error("You cannot change the number of rows, the matrix columns size is static.");

        if(isColStatic and NBCOLS != i_NbCols)
          throw std::runtime_error("You cannot change the number of columns, the matrix columns size is static.");

        internalChangeSize(i_NbRows, i_NbCols, DefaultValue);
      }

      /** @brief function used to change the size of the matrix
       *         This method requires a default value for filling
       *         any new row / column.
       *
       *  @param i_NewShape   IN : New shape of the matrix
       *  @param DefaultValue IN : Default value used to fill the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void changeSize(const std::pair<size_t, size_t>& i_NewShape, const TYPE &DefaultValue)
      {

        changeSize(i_NewShape.first, i_NewShape.second, DefaultValue);
      }

      /** @brief function used to transpose the current matrix.
       *         If the matrix is dynamically allocated, it's shape
       *         might be changed by the function
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void transpose()
      {
        // Error handlingmatrixData
        if (isEmpty())
          throw std::runtime_error("The transpose function can not be called on an empty matrix");

        if ((isRowStatic or isColStatic) and getNbRows() != getNbCols())
          throw std::runtime_error("The transpose function can not be called on a non square matrix with at least one static component");

        // The transposed Matrix is built and replaces the old data
        std::vector<std::vector<TYPE>> newData(getNbCols(), std::vector<TYPE>(getNbRows(), (*this)(0,0)));

        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < getNbCols() ; i += 1)
          for (size_t j = 0 ; j < getNbRows() ; j += 1)
            newData[i][j] = (*this)(i,j);

        matrixData = std::move(newData);
      }

      /** @brief () operator. returns a reference to
       *         the value at row i, column j
       *
       *  @return const TYPE&
       */
      const TYPE& operator()(size_t i_Row, size_t i_Col) const
      {
        try
        {
          return matrixData.at(i_Row).at(i_Col);
        }
        catch(std::out_of_range& e)
        {
          const auto MatrixShape = this->shape();
          std::ostringstream SS;
          SS << "Indexes : (" << i_Row << ", " << i_Col << ") are out of bounds of the Matrix : " << "(" << MatrixShape.first << ", " << MatrixShape.second << ")";
          throw std::runtime_error(SS.str());
        }
      }

      /** @brief () operator. returns a reference to
       *         the value at row i, column j
       *
       *  @return const TYPE&
       */
      TYPE& operator()(size_t i_Row, size_t i_Col)
      {
        try
        {
          return matrixData.at(i_Row).at(i_Col);
        }
        catch(std::out_of_range& e)
        {
          const auto MatrixShape = this->shape();
          std::ostringstream SS;
          SS << "Indexes : (" << i_Row << ", " << i_Col << ") are out of bounds of the Matrix : " << "(" << MatrixShape.first << ", " << MatrixShape.second << ")";
          throw std::runtime_error(SS.str());
        }
      }

      /** @brief = operator. It copies the right hand side
       *         into the left hand size Matrix. If the sizes are
       *         different and the left hand side is static, the copy
       *         fails
       *  @param rhs  IN : Right hand side matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      template<typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
      Matrix<TYPE, NBROWS, NBCOLS>& operator=(const Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> &rhs)
      {
        const auto LhsShape = this->shape();
        const auto RhsShape = rhs.shape();

        // Error handling
        if ((isRowStatic and (this->getNbRows() != rhs.getNbRows())) or
            (isColStatic and (this->getNbCols() != rhs.getNbCols())))
        {
          std::ostringstream SS;
          SS << "Impossible to fit data from a matrix of size (" << rhs.getNbRows() << ", " << rhs.getNbCols() << ") into"
                " a static matrix of size (" << this->getNbRows() << ", " << this->getNbCols() << ")";
          throw std::runtime_error(SS.str());
        }

        // If both matrices are empty, we dont need to do anything
        if(not(isEmpty() and rhs.isEmpty()))
        {
          // else, change the size only if necessary, taking a default value in one of the non empty matrices in order not to call the default constructor
          if (LhsShape != RhsShape )
          {
            if(not isEmpty())
            {
              changeSize(RhsShape, (*this)(0,0));
            }
            else if(not rhs.isEmpty())
            {
              changeSize(RhsShape, rhs(0,0));
            }
          }
        }

        matrixData = rhs.getMatrixData();
        return *this;
      }

      /** @brief move = operator. It moves the right hand side
       *         into the left hand size Matrix. If the sizes are
       *         different and the left hand side is static, the copy
       *         fails
       *  @param rhs  IN : Right hand side matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      template<typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
      Matrix<TYPE, NBROWS, NBCOLS>& operator=(Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS>&& rhs)
      {
        const auto LhsShape = this->shape();
        const auto RhsShape = rhs.shape();

        // Error handling
        if ((isRowStatic and (this->getNbRows() != rhs.getNbRows())) or
            (isColStatic and (this->getNbCols() != rhs.getNbCols())))
        {
          std::ostringstream SS;
          SS << "Impossible to fit data from a matrix of size (" << rhs.getNbRows() << ", " << rhs.getNbCols() << ") into"
                " a static matrix of size (" << this->getNbRows() << ", " << this->getNbCols() << ")";
          throw std::runtime_error(SS.str());
        }

        // If both matrices are empty, we dont need to resize anything
        if(not(isEmpty() and rhs.isEmpty()))
        {
          // else, change the size only if necessary, taking a default value in one of the non empty matrices in order not to call the default constructor
          if (LhsShape != RhsShape )
          {
            if(not isEmpty())
            {
              changeSize(RhsShape, (*this)(0,0));
            }
            else if(not rhs.isEmpty())
            {
              changeSize(RhsShape, rhs(0,0));
            }
          }
        }

        matrixData = std::move(rhs.matrixData);
        return *this;
      }

      /** @brief += operator. It adds the right hand side
       *         into the left hand size Matrix. If the sizes are
       *         different the operator fails
       *
       *  @param i_NbRows  IN : New number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbCols  IN : New number of columns of the matrix
       *  @param io_Matrix IN : Matrix which size will be reduced
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      template<typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
      Matrix<TYPE, NBROWS, NBCOLS>& operator+=(const Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> &rhs)
      {
        // Error handling
        if(this->isEmpty() or rhs.isEmpty())
          throw std::runtime_error("Adding empty matrices is forbidden");

        if (rhs.shape() != this->shape())
          throw std::runtime_error("Adding matrices of different shapes is forbidden");

        for(size_t i = 0; i < getNbRows()  ; i += 1)
          for(size_t j = 0 ; j < getNbCols() ; j += 1)
            matrixData[i][j] += rhs(i,j);

        return *this;
      }


      /** @brief + operator. It adds both sides of the "+" sign
       *         and returns a static size matrix. Both sides
       *         have to be of the same shape, otherwise the
       *         operator fails.
       *
       *  @param rhs IN : Matrix, right side of the equation
       *
       *  @return Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) + (*this)(0,0)), NBROWS, NBCOLS, true>.
       */
      template<typename LHSTYPE, size_t LHSNBROWS, size_t LHSNBCOLS, typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
      friend auto operator+(const Matrix<LHSTYPE, LHSNBROWS, LHSNBCOLS> &lhs, const Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> &rhs) ->
             Matrix<decltype(lhs(0,0) + rhs(0,0)), LHSNBROWS == DYNAMIC ? RHSNBROWS : DYNAMIC,
                                                   LHSNBCOLS == DYNAMIC ? RHSNBCOLS : DYNAMIC>;

      /** @brief operator* It multiplies both sides of the "*" sign
       *         and returns a static size matrix. Both sides
       *         have to have compatible sizes, (lhs.columns == rhs.cols)
       *         otherwise, the operator fails.
       *
       *  @param rhs IN : Matrix, right side of the equation
       *
       *  @return Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) * (*this)(0,0)), this->getNbRows(), rhs.getNbCols(), true>
       */
      template<typename LHSTYPE, size_t LHSNBROWS, size_t LHSNBCOLS, typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
      friend auto operator*(const Matrix<LHSTYPE, LHSNBROWS, LHSNBCOLS> &lhs, const Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> &rhs) -> Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) * lhs(0,0)), LHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS>;


    private:
      /** @brief function used to change the size of the matrix
       *         This method does not require a default value,
       *         hence it is default initialized. It does not check if the matrix is static or not
       *
       *  @param i_NbRows IN : New number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbCols IN : New number of columns of the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void internalChangeSize(const size_t i_NbRows, const size_t i_NbCols)
      {
        // Error handling
        if (i_NbRows <= 0 or i_NbCols <= 0)
          throw std::runtime_error("The number or rows and columns should be a positive integer");

        matrixData.resize(i_NbRows, std::vector<TYPE>(i_NbCols, TYPE()));
        for (auto& row : matrixData)
          row.resize(i_NbCols, TYPE());
      }

      /** @brief function used to change the size of the matrix
       *         This method requires a default value for filling
       *         any new row / column. It does not check if the matrix is static or not
       *
       *  @param i_NbRows     IN : New number of rows of the matrix
       *  @param o_NbCols     IN : New number of columns of the matrix
       *  @param DefaultValue IN : Default value used to fill the matrix
       *
       *  @return Void.
       */
      void internalChangeSize(const size_t i_NbRows, const size_t i_NbCols, const TYPE &DefaultValue)
      {
        // error handling
        if (i_NbRows <= 0 or i_NbCols <= 0)
          throw std::runtime_error("The number or rows and columns has to be a positive integer");

        matrixData.resize(i_NbRows, std::vector<TYPE>(i_NbCols, DefaultValue));
        for (auto& row : matrixData)
          row.resize(i_NbCols, DefaultValue);
      }
    };

  /** @brief + operator. It adds both sides of the "+" sign
   *         and returns a static size matrix. Both sides
   *         have to be of the same shape, otherwise the
   *         operator fails.
   *
   *  @param rhs IN : Matrix, right side of the equation
   *
   *  @return Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) + (*this)(0,0)), NBROWS, NBCOLS, true>.
   */
  template<typename LHSTYPE, size_t LHSNBROWS, size_t LHSNBCOLS, typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
    auto operator+(const Matrix<LHSTYPE, LHSNBROWS, LHSNBCOLS> &lhs, const Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> &rhs) ->
      Matrix<decltype(lhs(0,0) + rhs(0,0)), LHSNBROWS == DYNAMIC ? RHSNBROWS : DYNAMIC,
                                            LHSNBCOLS == DYNAMIC ? RHSNBCOLS : DYNAMIC>
    {
      // Error handling
      if(lhs.isEmpty() or rhs.isEmpty())
        throw std::runtime_error("Adding empty matrices is forbidden");

      if (rhs.shape() != lhs.shape())
        throw std::runtime_error("Adding matrices of different shapes is forbidden");

      Matrix<decltype(lhs(0,0) + rhs(0,0)), LHSNBROWS == DYNAMIC ? RHSNBROWS : DYNAMIC,
                                            LHSNBCOLS == DYNAMIC ? RHSNBCOLS : DYNAMIC> newMatrix(lhs.getNbRows(), lhs.getNbCols(), lhs(0,0));

      for(size_t i = 0 ; i < rhs.getNbRows() ; i += 1)
        for(size_t j = 0 ; j < rhs.getNbCols() ; j += 1)
          newMatrix(i, j) = lhs(i,j) + rhs(i,j);

      return newMatrix;
    }

  /** @brief operator* It multiplies both sides of the "*" sign
   *         and returns a static size matrix. Both sides
   *         have to have compatible sizes, (lhs.columns == rhs.cols)
   *         otherwise, the operator fails.
   *
   *  @param rhs IN : Matrix, right side of the equation
   *
   *  @return Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) * (*this)(0,0)), this->getNbRows(), rhs.getNbCols(), true>
   */
  template<typename LHSTYPE, size_t LHSNBROWS, size_t LHSNBCOLS, typename RHSTYPE, size_t RHSNBROWS, size_t RHSNBCOLS>
  auto operator*(const Matrix<LHSTYPE, LHSNBROWS, LHSNBCOLS> &lhs, const Matrix<RHSTYPE, RHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> &rhs) -> Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) * lhs(0,0)), LHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS>
  {
    // error handling
    if(lhs.isEmpty() or rhs.isEmpty())
      throw std::runtime_error("Multiplying empty matrices is forbidden");

    if(lhs.getNbCols() != rhs.getNbRows())
      throw std::runtime_error("The size of the matrices is incompatible with matrix multiplication");

    Matrix<decltype(rhs(0,0) * lhs(0,0)), LHSNBROWS, RHSNBCOLS> newMatrix(lhs.getNbRows(), rhs.getNbCols(), lhs(0,0));

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < lhs.getNbRows() ; i += 1)
    {
      for(size_t j = 0 ; j < rhs.getNbCols(); j += 1)
      {
        decltype(rhs(0,0) * lhs(0,0)) sum = lhs(i,0) * rhs(0,j); // Compute the first element of the sum in order not to call the default constructor
        for(size_t k = 1 ; k < lhs.getNbRows() ; k += 1)
        {
          sum += lhs(i,k) * rhs(k,j);
        }
        newMatrix(i, j) = std::move(sum);
      }
    }
    return newMatrix;
  }

  /** @brief operator<< outputs the Matrix into a stream
   *
   *  @param i_Matrix IN  : Matrix to output
   *  @param o_OS     OUT : Stream in which the matrix must be fitted
   *
   *  @return std::ostream&
   */
  template <typename TYPE, size_t NBROWS, size_t NBCOLS>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o_OS, const Matrix<TYPE, NBROWS, NBCOLS>& i_Matrix)
  {
      return o_OS << i_Matrix.toString();
  }
} /* namespace Mat */
```

**[EDIT]**
As requested, i have written this main in which i instanciate some matrices, add and multiply them. Some are static, some dynamic.
i have not shown the case where only one dimension of the matrix is dynamic and the other static (like in a dynamic size vector for instance), but this works the same.

*I used these options when compiling when working with the class:
-std=c++11 -O0 -g -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -fmessage-length=0
However, for the implict conversion behavior to work in the test main, -Wconversion shall not be used.*

````
#include <iostream>

#include "Matrix.h"

int main()
{
  // Test of static Matrix operations
  // ==============================================
  std::cout << "==============================================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "===============STATIC MATRICES================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "==============================================" << std::endl;
  mat::Matrix<int, 3,2> StaticMatrix_1(21);
  mat::Matrix<float, 3,2> StaticMatrix3x2(2.0);
  mat::Matrix<float, 3,3> StaticMatrix3x3(2.0);

  // Resizing a static matrix should throw if it changes the size of the matrix only
  // should not throw
  StaticMatrix_1.changeSize(3, 2);
  try
  {
    StaticMatrix_1.changeSize(4, 5);
    std::cout << "Did not throw ==> problem" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error& E)
  {
  }

  std::cout << "STATIC MATRICES USED:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix_1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix3x2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix3x3 << std::endl;

  // test of Matrix multiplication: Should yield a 3 by 2 matrix, full of 12.0 floats
  std::cout << "TEST_ADDITION FLOAT + FLOAT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix3x3 * StaticMatrix3x2 << std::endl;

  // test of matrix addition: This should yield a matrix of floats as int + float does yield a float
  std::cout << "TEST_ADDITION INT + FLOAT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix_1 + StaticMatrix3x2 << std::endl;

  // Test of matrix addition with different sizes (should throw)
  try
  {
    StaticMatrix3x2 + StaticMatrix3x3;
    std::cout << "Did not throw ==> problem" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error& E)
  {
  }

  // This property should be commutative
  std::cout << "TEST_ADDITION FLOAT + INT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix3x2 + StaticMatrix_1 << std::endl;

  std::cout << "TEST_MATRIX_MULTIPLICATION" << std::endl;
  std::cout << StaticMatrix3x3 * StaticMatrix3x2 << std::endl;
  // This should throw (incompatible sizes for multiplication)
  try
  {
    StaticMatrix3x2 * StaticMatrix3x3;
    std::cout << "Did not throw ==> problem" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error& E)
  {
  }

  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
  std::cout << "==============================================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "===============DYNAMIC MATRICES===============" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "==============================================" << std::endl;

  // We use the same types, contents and sizes
  mat::Matrix<int,   mat::DYNAMIC, mat::DYNAMIC> DynamicMatrix_1(3, 2, 21);
  mat::Matrix<float, mat::DYNAMIC, mat::DYNAMIC> DynamicMatrix3x2(3, 2, 2.0);
  mat::Matrix<float, mat::DYNAMIC, mat::DYNAMIC> DynamicMatrix3x3(3, 3, 2.0);

  std::cout << "DYNAMYC MATRICES USED:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix_1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix3x2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix3x3 << std::endl;

  // Resizing a dynamic matrix should throw only if the requested size is <= 0
  // should not throw
  DynamicMatrix_1.changeSize(1, 1);
  DynamicMatrix_1.changeSize(3, 2);
  try
  {
    DynamicMatrix_1.changeSize(0, 0);
    std::cout << "Did not throw ==> problem" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error& E)
  {
  }

  // test of Matrix multiplication: Should yield a 3 by 2 matrix, full of 12.0 floats
  std::cout << "TEST_ADDITION FLOAT + FLOAT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix3x3 * DynamicMatrix3x2 << std::endl;

  // test of matrix addition: This should yield a matrix of floats as int + float does yield a float
  std::cout << "TEST_ADDITION INT + FLOAT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix_1 + DynamicMatrix3x2 << std::endl;

  // Test of matrix addition with different sizes (should throw)
  try
  {
    DynamicMatrix3x2 + DynamicMatrix3x3;
    std::cout << "Did not throw ==> problem" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error& E)
  {
  }

  // This property should be commutative
  std::cout << "TEST_ADDITION FLOAT + INT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix3x2 + DynamicMatrix_1 << std::endl;

  std::cout << "TEST_MATRIX_MULTIPLICATION" << std::endl;
  std::cout << DynamicMatrix3x3 * DynamicMatrix3x2 << std::endl;
  // This should throw (incompatible sizes for multiplication)
  try
  {
    DynamicMatrix3x2 * DynamicMatrix3x3;
    std::cout << "Did not throw ==> problem" << std::endl;
  }
  catch(std::runtime_error& E)
  {
  }

  return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: Very well elaborated. Thank you for that. Hopefully you will get some answers.

Comment: Do you have some unit tests you could add to demonstrate usage?

Comment: Do you mean real unit tests (i could write some of those using catch if you want) or a little main where i create some objects and use them?